# Why can't I return bigger values from main function?

Tags: c++, linux, exit-code

I am trying to return a bigger value like 1000 from my main function, but when I type `echo $?` it displays 0.

If I return a smaller value like 100 it displays the correct value.

**My Code:**

```
int main(void)
{
     return 1000;
}
```

Is there any limitation on the values which we can return?

Comment: I get **232** for `return 1000;` and **233** for `return 1001;`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two related concepts here: C exit status, and bash return code. They both cover the range 0-255, but bash uses numbers above 126 for it's own purposes, so it would be confusing to return those from your program.

To be safe limit exit status codes to 0-127, as that is most portable, at least that is implied by http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit.

The C exit status is put into the bash $? variable after execution, but bash uses 127 to indicate 'command not found' so you may want to avoid that. [Bash reference page](http://www.ofb.net/gnu/bash/bashref_43.html).

Bash also uses 128-255 for signals - they indicate the process was killed with a signal:
`exit code = 128 + signal number`. So you might be able to get away with using numbers close to 255 as it unlikely that signal numbers will go that high.

Beyond those common guide-lines there are many attempts to define what different numbers should mean: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html.

So it you want to return an arbitrary integer from your program, it's probably best to print it to stdout, and capture it with `VALUE=$(program)` from your bash script.

Comment: I believe the range is 0-255 (i.e. the range of `uint8_t`) on *NIX systems--not familiar with any systems with a max value of 127 (that would imply a signed return type equivalent to `int8_t`, but that would also imply a lower bound of -128.)

Comment: Besides telling an incorrect range (as @Jonathan noted), you also seem to confuse the program exit status (as reported by `waitpid(2)`) and the shell command exit status (as reported by `$?`). "128-255 are used for signals" only applies to the latter.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `main` (i.e. the exit status of the application) is limited to the range [0, 255] on *NIX. 1000 is out of range, and the OS treats it as 0, presumably.

Comment: No, at least in bash, an exit status greater than 255 returns the value modulo 256. 1000 will return 232

Comment: That's what I would assume, based on how C handles numbers, but the OP said he was getting 0 as his result.

Answer (score 2):

In Unix-land the return value of `main` is limited because `exit` there is limited to the range of an 8-bit byte.

In Windows there is a single value, `STILL_ACTIVE` with value 259, that is best avoided as process exit code.

Other than that, in Windows you can return a 32-bit code such as an `HRESULT` and that is commonly done.